# DNS configured in network manager but not working

Tags: networking, dns, resolvconf

I have 2 DNS configured in network manager for my connection (Selected DHCP Addresses only).

The DNS are working good if used with nslookup.

/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search domain.tld #edited
```

What dns is running on 127.0.1.1?

If I run `nslookup thehost` it won't work. But if I run `nslookup thehost 192.168.1.4` (the dns configured in network manager) it works.

So I would like to know which DNS is nslookup going through and what is happening after it. I suppose it is going to 127.0.1.1 but then I don't know which is this one (dnsmasq doesn't seem to be installed) and what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

*Network-manager* use **dnsmasq** as a non-caching local dns server to do it's resolving. It should forward DNS request to the DNS you have specified in network-manager config.

Seeing *127.0.1.1* in `/etc/resolv.conf` is normal.

It does not work because you miss *dnsmasq* which is a dependancy of network-manager.

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

It should correct your broken dependancy and install the missing *dnsmasq* package.

If not install it yourself, with

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq-base
```

Comment: I rebooted and now it is working correctly. In `/etc/dnsmasq.d/` there is only a file named `network-manager` and it has some comments and only this: `bind-interfaces`